# Displaying and editing Set values in PrimeFaces

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, jsf, primefaces

I have `JSF 2.2`, `PrimeFaces 3.5`, `Spring 3.1.3`, `Hibernate 4.1`, `MySQL` web app.

On home.xhtml I have a tabview with 3 nested dataTables for 3 entities (Users, Computers, Applications) and CRUD buttons (see screenshot). Every button calls a dialog window with a form to add/edit/delete entity.

I will provide all code that is somehow associated with a problem (you may not need to check them all, I just made sure that every part of code you may be interested in is present below.)

[image]

Please, consider the following script for creating entities and their corresponding classes:

```
CREATE TABLE computers (
computer_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
computer_name VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
ip_address VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
login VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
password VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(computer_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE applications (
app_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
app_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
vendor_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
license_required TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(app_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE computer_app (
computer_id INT,
app_id INT,
FOREIGN KEY (computer_id)
    REFERENCES computers(computer_id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY (app_id)
    REFERENCES applications(app_id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Computer.class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="computers", catalog="adminportal")
public class Computer  implements Serializable {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="computer_id", unique=true, nullable=false)
     private Integer computerId;

    @Column(name="computer_name", nullable=false, length=15)
     private String computerName;

    @Column(name="ip_address", unique=true, nullable=false, length=15)
     private String ipAddress;

    @Column(name="login", nullable=false, length=20)
     private String login;

    @Column(name="password", nullable=false, length=20)
     private String password;

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="computers")
     private Set<ComputerApp> computerApps = new HashSet<>(0);
```

Application.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="applications", catalog="adminportal")
public class Application  implements Serializable {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="app_id", unique=true, nullable=false)
     private Integer appId;

    @Column(name="app_name", nullable=false)
     private String appName;

    @Column(name="vendor_name", nullable=false)
     private String vendorName;

    @Column(name="license_required", nullable=false, columnDefinition = "BIT", length = 1)
     private boolean licenseRequired;

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="applications")
     private Set<ComputerApp> computerApps = new HashSet<>(0);
```

ComputerApp.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="computer_app" ,catalog="adminportal")
public class ComputerApp  implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    @AttributeOverrides( {
        @AttributeOverride(name="computerId", column=@Column(name="computer_id") ), 
        @AttributeOverride(name="appId", column=@Column(name="app_id") ) } )
     private ComputerAppId id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="app_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
     private Application applications;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="computer_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
     private Computer computers;
```

ComputerAppId.java:

```
@Embeddable
public class ComputerAppId implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "computer_id")
    private Integer computerId;

    @Column(name = "app_id")
    private Integer appId;
```

home.xhtml:

```
<p:tabView id="tab" orientation="left">

        <p:tab title="Users" rendered="#{request.isUserInRole('ROLE_ADMIN')}">

            <h:form id="form1">

                <h:panelGrid columns="9" >

                    <p:commandButton type="button" value="Add" onclick="dlg1.show()" />


                    <p:commandButton id="editUser" type="button" value="Edit" onclick="dlg2.show()" disabled="#{homeBean.selectedUser == null}"/>


                    <p:commandButton id="deleteUser" type="button" onclick="confirmation1.show()" value="Delete" disabled="#{homeBean.selectedUser == null}"/>
                    <p:confirmDialog id="delete1" header="Confirmation" widgetVar="confirmation1" >
                        <p:commandButton value="Yes" update=":tab:users" process="@this" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="ui-icon-check"
                                         oncomplete="confirmation1.hide()" action="#{homeBean.deleteUser}" />
                        <p:commandButton value="No" onclick="confirmation1.hide()" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" icon="ui-icon-close"/>
                        <f:facet name="message">
                            <p:outputPanel>
                                <h:outputFormat value="#{homeBean.deleteUserMsg}"/>
                            </p:outputPanel>
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:confirmDialog>

                </h:panelGrid>

            </h:form>


            <p:dataTable id="users" var="user" value="#{homeBean.users}" 
                         scrollable="true" scrollHeight="250" selectionMode="single"
                         selection="#{homeBean.selectedUser}" rowKey="#{user.userId}"
                         sortMode="single">

                <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{homeBean.onUserRowSelect}" update=":tab:form1:deleteUser, :tab:form1:editUser, :tab:form1:delete1, :dlg2form:panel2"/> 

                <p:column headerText="Login" sortBy="#{user.login}">  
                    <h:outputText value="#{user.login}"/>
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Password" sortBy="#{user.password}">  
                    <h:outputText value="#{user.password}"/>
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Role" sortBy="#{user.role}">  
                    <h:outputText value="#{user.role}"/>
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Name" sortBy="#{user.firstName}">  
                    <h:outputText value="#{user.firstName}"/>
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Surname" sortBy="#{user.lastName}">  
                    <h:outputText value="#{user.lastName}"/>
                </p:column>

            </p:dataTable>

            <ex:exporter target=":tab:users" fileName="Users"/>

        </p:tab>

        <p:tab title="Computers">

            <h:form id="form2">

                <h:panelGrid columns="9" rendered="#{request.isUserInRole('ROLE_ADMIN')}">

                    <p:commandButton type="button" value="Add" onclick="dlg3.show()"/>


                    <p:commandButton id="editComp" type="button" value="Edit" onclick="dlg4.show()" disabled="#{homeBean.selectedComputer == null}"/>


                    <p:commandButton id="deleteComp" type="button" onclick="confirmation2.show()" value="Delete" disabled="#{homeBean.selectedComputer == null}"/>
                    <p:confirmDialog id="delete2" header="Confirmation"
                                     severity="alert" widgetVar="confirmation2">
                        <p:commandButton value="Yes" update=":tab:computers" process="@this" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="ui-icon-check"
                                         oncomplete="confirmation2.hide()" action="#{homeBean.deleteComputer}"/>
                        <p:commandButton value="No" onclick="confirmation2.hide()" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" icon="ui-icon-close"/>
                        <f:facet name="message">
                            <p:outputPanel>
                                <h:outputFormat value="#{homeBean.deleteCompMsg}"/>
                            </p:outputPanel>
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:confirmDialog>

                </h:panelGrid>

            </h:form>


            <p:dataTable id="computers" var="computer" value="#{homeBean.computers}" 
                         scrollable="true" scrollHeight="250" selectionMode="single"
                         selection="#{homeBean.selectedComputer}" rowKey="#{computer.computerId}"
                         sortMode="single" >
                <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{homeBean.onCompRowSelect}" update=":tab:form2:editComp, :tab:form2:deleteComp, :tab:form2:delete2, :dlg4form:panel4"/> 

                <p:column headerText="Login" sortBy="#{computer.login}">  
                    <h:outputText value="#{computer.login}"/>  
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Password" sortBy="#{computer.password}">  
                    <h:outputText value="#{computer.password}"/>  
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Name" sortBy="#{computer.computerName}" > 
                    <h:outputText value="#{computer.computerName}"/>  
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="IP address" sortBy="#{computer.ipAddress}">  
                    <h:outputText value="#{computer.ipAddress}"/>  
                </p:column>

            </p:dataTable>

            <ex:exporter target=":tab:computers" fileName="Computers"/>

        </p:tab>

        <p:tab title="Applications">


            <h:form id="form3" rendered="#{request.isUserInRole('ROLE_ADMIN')}">

                <h:panelGrid columns="9">

                    <p:commandButton type="button" value="Add" onclick="dlg5.show()"/>


                    <p:commandButton id="editApp" type="button" value="Edit" onclick="dlg6.show()" disabled="#{homeBean.selectedApplication == null}"/>


                    <p:commandButton id="deleteApp" type="button" onclick="confirmation3.show()" value="Delete" disabled="#{homeBean.selectedApplication == null}"/>
                    <p:confirmDialog id="delete3" message="Are you sure you want to delete this application?" header="Confirmation"
                                     severity="alert" widgetVar="confirmation3">
                        <p:commandButton value="Yes" update=":tab:applications" process="@this" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="ui-icon-check"
                                         oncomplete="confirmation3.hide()" action="#{homeBean.deleteApplication}"/>
                        <p:commandButton value="No" onclick="confirmation3.hide()" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" icon="ui-icon-close"/>
                        <f:facet name="message">
                            <p:outputPanel>
                                <h:outputFormat value="#{homeBean.deleteAppMsg}"/>
                            </p:outputPanel>
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:confirmDialog>

                </h:panelGrid>

            </h:form>

            <p:dataTable id="applications" var="app" value="#{homeBean.applications}" 
                         scrollable="true" scrollHeight="250" selectionMode="single"
                         selection="#{homeBean.selectedApplication}" rowKey="#{app.appId}"
                         sortMode="single" >

                <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{homeBean.onAppRowSelect}" update=":tab:form3:editApp, :tab:form3:deleteApp, :tab:form3:delete3, :dlg6form:panel6"/>

                <p:column headerText="Name" sortBy="#{app.appName}">  
                    <h:outputText value="#{app.appName}"/>  
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Vendor" sortBy="#{app.vendorName}" >  
                    <h:outputText value="#{app.vendorName}"/>  
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="License required" sortBy="#{app.licenseRequired}">  
                    <h:outputText value="#{app.licenseRequired}"/>  
                </p:column>

            </p:dataTable>

            <ex:exporter target=":tab:applications" fileName="Applications" />

        </p:tab>

    </p:tabView>

    <!--DIALOGS ARE NOT PRESENT SINCE POST IS TOO LONG-->

        </h:body>

</ui:component>
```

HomeBean.java:

```
@Component
@Scope("session")
public class HomeBean extends BaseBean {

    private static final String editUserBtn = "tab:form1:editUser";
    private static final String deleteUserBtn = "tab:form1:deleteUser";
    private static final String editCompBtn = "tab:form2:editComp";
    private static final String deleteCompBtn = "tab:form2:deleteComp";
    private static final String editAppBtn = "tab:form3:editApp";
    private static final String deleteAppBtn = "tab:form3:deleteApp";

    private List<User> users;
    private List<Computer> computers;
    private List<Application> applications;
    private User selectedUser, newUser;
    private Computer selectedComputer, newComputer;
    private Application selectedApplication, newApplication;
    private String deleteUserMsg, deleteCompMsg, deleteAppMsg;
    private RequestContext rc;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        setUsers(hibernateDBManager.getAllUsers());
        setComputers(hibernateDBManager.getAllComputers());
        setApplications(hibernateDBManager.getAllApplications());
        newUser = new User();
        newComputer = new Computer();
        newApplication = new Application();
        rc = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
    }

    public void addUser() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        if (hibernateDBManager.insertUser(newUser)) {
            users.add(newUser);
            newUser = new User();
            updateUserButtons();
        }
    }

    public void editUser() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        if (hibernateDBManager.updateUser(selectedUser)) {
            users.set(users.indexOf(selectedUser), selectedUser);
            selectedUser = null;
            updateUserButtons();
        }
    }

    public void deleteUser() throws IOException {
        if (selectedUser != null) {
            if (hibernateDBManager.deleteUserById(selectedUser.getUserId()) > 0) {
                users.remove(selectedUser);
                selectedUser = null;
                updateUserButtons();
            }
        }
    }

    public void addComputer() {
        if (newComputer != null && hibernateDBManager.insertComputer(newComputer)) {
            computers.add(newComputer);
            newComputer = new Computer();
            updateCompButtons();
        }
    }

    public void editComputer() {
        if (hibernateDBManager.updateComputer(selectedComputer)) {
            computers.set(computers.indexOf(selectedComputer), selectedComputer);
            selectedComputer = null;
            updateCompButtons();
        }
    }

    public void deleteComputer() {
        if (selectedComputer != null) {
            if (hibernateDBManager.deleteComputerById(selectedComputer.getComputerId()) > 0) {
                computers.remove(selectedComputer);
                selectedComputer = null;
                updateCompButtons();
            }
        }
    }

    public void addApplication() {
        if (newApplication != null && hibernateDBManager.insertApplication(newApplication)) {
            applications.add(newApplication);
            newApplication = new Application();
            updateAppButtons();
        }
    }

    public void editApplication() {
        if (hibernateDBManager.updateApplication(selectedApplication)) {
            applications.set(applications.indexOf(selectedApplication), selectedApplication);
            selectedApplication = null;
            updateAppButtons();
        } 
    }

    public void deleteApplication() {
        if (selectedApplication != null) {
            if (hibernateDBManager.deleteApplicationById(selectedApplication.getAppId()) > 0) {
                applications.remove(selectedApplication);
                selectedApplication = null;
                updateAppButtons();
            }
        }
    }

    public void onUserRowSelect(SelectEvent event) {
        setSelectedUser((User) event.getObject());
        setDeleteUserMsg("Are you sure you want to delete user "
                + selectedUser.getFirstName() + " " + selectedUser.getLastName() + "?");
    }

    public void onCompRowSelect(SelectEvent event) {
        setSelectedComputer((Computer) event.getObject());
        deleteCompMsg = "Are you sure you want to delete computer "
                + selectedComputer.getComputerName()
                + " (" + selectedComputer.getIpAddress() + ") ?";
    }

    public void onAppRowSelect(SelectEvent event) {
        setSelectedApplication((Application) event.getObject());
        deleteAppMsg = "Are you sure you want to delete application "
                + selectedApplication.getAppName() + "?";
    }

    protected void updateUserButtons() {
        rc.update(editUserBtn);
        rc.update(deleteUserBtn);
    }

    protected void updateCompButtons() {
        rc.update(editCompBtn);
        rc.update(deleteCompBtn);
    }

    protected void updateAppButtons() {
        rc.update(editAppBtn);
        rc.update(deleteAppBtn);
    }
    //Getters/setters

}
```

My target is to find the best way to display Set values (Set  in Computer) in a dataTable or somehow else manage adding and removing applications from/to selected computers.

Every answer is highly appreciated and responded quickly!

Thank you.

Comment: There is waaaay too much noise in here, not stuff that one can simply ignore.

Comment: your mapping of entities from the tables is not right. you should not have an entity called ComputerApp. You need Computer, Application, and a @ManyToMany relationship between them. do some research on this type of relationship in JPA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I used PrimeFaces's `<picklist>` element as a best approach in my issue.